# ¿El metodo finalize() de una clase en java hace exactamente lo mismo que el metodo ondestroy() para android?

Tags: java, android, programación-móvil

Realmente es algo curioso, ya que el método finalize por defecto en la clase object hace tareas de limpieza antes que el objeto se a eliminada de la memoria, que es algo que también hace la clase onDestroy.

Asi que me surge esa duda **en que se diferencian** y por que para los desarrolladores de android decidieron implementar `onDestroy()` si se ya se tenia `finalize()`.

Estoy investigando acerca de ello pero que opinan ustedes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se pueden decir que son similares :

- El método `onDestroy()` es llamado cuando se finaliza la Activity y se realiza antes de destruir la `Activity`, ya sea porque se llamo el método `finish()` o porque el sistema operativo requiere memoria.
- El método `finalize()` se llama cuando el objeto es finalizado por el GC.

**Son similares porque:** en ambos métodos puedes realizar acciones antes de ser destruida la Activity o el Objeto.

**La diferencia es:** [finalize()](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Object.html) es llamada por el recolector de basura (Gargage Collector) mientras que [onDestroy()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onDestroy()) se llama cuando se ejecuta el método `finish ()` o porque el sistema está destruyendo temporalmente esta instancia de la actividad para ahorrar memoria.**

---

De la documentación:

> [finalize()](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Object.html) Llamado por el recolector de basura (Gargage Collector)  de un objeto cuando la
>   recolección de elementos no utilizados determina que no hay más
>   referencias al objeto.
>
> [onDestroy()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onDestroy()) La última llamada que reciba antes de que la actividad sea
>   destruida. Esto puede suceder ya sea porque la actividad está
>   terminando (alguien llamó finish () o porque el sistema está
>   destruyendo temporalmente esta instancia de la actividad para ahorrar
>   memoria. Puede distinguir estos dos escenarios con el método
>   isFinishing ().

El método `finalize()` para una Activity existe, pero recuerda algo importante, **no trates de ser más inteligente que el Garbage Collector, ya que el decidirá cuando eliminar la instancia.** Lo comento porque anteriormente era común ver esta llamada para tratar de liberar memoria ⤜(ʘ_ʘ)⤏, además su ejecución la determina el Garbage Collector.

Answer (score 1):

Cuando el método `onDestroy` se ejecuta en una aplicación android hay 2 razones

- Alguien (o Algo) llamo al `finish()` de la `Activity`
- El sistema operativo necesita liberar memoria.

Cuando se ejecuta el método `finalize()` ocurre exactamente lo mismo (Necesidad de liberar memoria o bien, no identificar referencias al objeto en cuestion) pero es llamado por el recolector. **Ojo, que no hay manera de saber cuando recoletor de basura va a llamar a la funcion `finalize()` y si se necesita utilizar este metodo muy probablemente hay algo mal en su logica y codigo. De ejecutarlo, se encarga el recolector.**

Ambos métodos puedes sobre-escribirlos y agregar código para saber o ver cuando tu objecto va a ser destruido.